# ASM CALL Before PUSH

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering

I'm a little new to ASM, but I was wondering if my assumption is correct. I was using OllyDBG on a dll and I saw it did something like this:

`CALL DllName.373DC040`

`PUSH 1`

Does this mean it pushed the value of 1 to the address it called? If not, what would this mean?

Thank you in advance.

I also just wanted to say thank you for the down votes. They're really helping me learn.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but SO is not a learning site either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there are two instructions that are completely independent of each other.

```
CALL DllName.373DC040
```

This does an assembly-language function call to the code located at the address "DllName.373DC040".  The debugger is showing you a symbolic form of the address; the actual value will be a number either hard-coded into the program or generated by the operating system when the program is loaded.

```
PUSH 1
```

Once the prior function call returns, this puts the number "1" on the top of the stack.